# What is the meaning of "stock" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Following are the instructions for stock Ubuntu 16.04. If you are using a different OS, please install the packages accordingly.

Thank you

Comment: The usage probably derives from automobiles, where "stock" refers to an automobile with no after-purchase modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stock) says, one of the meanings of *stock* is:

> 41. kept regularly on hand, as for use or sale; staple; standard:
>           *stock articles*

In this context, they mean **a standard unmodified Ubuntu distribution from *Canonical***, as opposed to derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Here "stock" means "unmodified".  You see that use most commonly in the expression ["stock car"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_car_racing)

It comes from the sense of a piece of store merchandise.  If something is "stock", it is just as you bought it from the store.